# What was Namor doing in Latveria during the Stamford Incident?

Tags: marvel, comics, marvel-civil-war

In the "Civil War: Wolverine" [tie-in](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Civil_War_(comics)#Trade_Paperbacks), we witness a scene in Latveria where two shadowy figures discuss the Stamford Incident and view footage of Namorita's death. We later find that the "my liege" in this scene is not Victor von Doom, but is in fact [**King Namor**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Namor) of Atlantis:

[image]

Namor later arrives in the U.S. to deal with Nitro & Wolverine himself, but no mention is made of a previous trip or involvement with Doctor Doom. **What was Namor doing in Latveria at this time?**